# Removing keys when rendering schema org

Tags: php, arrays, json, wordpress, schema.org

I am rendering schema.org data but I am having a problem when I foreach the data from array to json. The key of the item in array is inserted before the item like this:

```
{
"@context": "http://schema.org",
"@type": "FAQPage",
"mainEntity":   {
    "0":        {
        "@type": "Question",
        "name": "Question 1",
        "acceptedAnswer":           {
            "@type": "Answer",
            "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."
        }
    },
    "1":        {
        "@type": "Question",
        "name": "Question 2",
        "acceptedAnswer":           {
            "@type": "Answer",
            "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."
        }
    },
    "2":        {
        "@type": "Question",
        "name": "Question 3",
        "acceptedAnswer":           {
            "@type": "Answer",
            "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."
        }
    }
}
```

}

I am using these functions:

This one, when I am rendering FAQ to frontend.

```
KT_PP_JSONLD::addItem([
        '@type' => 'Question',
        'name' => $Faq["kt-pp-loan-faq-question"],
        'acceptedAnswer' => [
                   "@type" => 'Answer',
                   "text" => $Faq["kt-pp-loan-faq-answer"],
        ],
]);
```

Which is defined in Schema generator this way:

```
public static function addItem($item)
{
    if (KT::arrayIssetAndNotEmpty($item)) {
        self::$items[] = $item;
    }
}
```

This one in Schema generator.

```
public static function addFaq()
{
    self::addCustom([
        "@context" => "http://schema.org",
        "@type" => "FAQPage",
        "mainEntity" => self::$items
    ]);
}
```

Can anybody help me with this please?

Comment: Please share the code which transforms array to JSON.

Comment: Schema generator is your own custom class or it is some kind of vendor library? It looks like it doesn't use `json_encode` because native encode would transform array with incremental keys (0,1,2,3) into the JSON array without keys. `json_encode(['wow','this','is','cool'])` results into the `["wow","this","is","cool"]` (tested on PHP 5.6, 7.2, 7.4 and 8.0). At all, you can give a shot to `array_values(self::$items)` and see if it helps but it looks like a Schema validator missuse.

Comment: @Jax-p yes, it is custom class. And array_values() is not working..

Comment: The JSON is not valid, which means that you cannot walk the tree.